# How can we make sure that only one instance of any application in running even in 2 different JVM's

Tags: java, unix, operating-system

I was asked this question at an interview.
Lets say VLC player is there and running on our OS.
Now when we again try to launch VLC , that should not happen.

alternatively, say we have two command windows, we runn same java program in two different Windows. How can we ensure only one runs.

Is this OS dependent thing?
Whats implementation?

I read something about MUTEX/Semaphore but I guess that is inside one JVM only.

Comment: There must be some shared resource that is somehow checked, and this is necessarily external to the JVM and the core JDK classes.  Could be a file, socket, some sort of web resource, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a pid file to disk, in a known location, indicating that the application is already running. Then, on startup, look for that file. If it's there, the application is already running, so exit.

Left as an exercise to the reader: ensuring that the pid file is removed even when the app crashes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "Deletion will be attempted only for normal termination of the virtual machine" `:'(`

Comment: Yes, it is not a very reliable technique because it involves explicit deletion operation by the JVM instead of relying on some foolproof OS-level feature. But that's only to be expected: otherwise Java would have a feature which would be impossible to implement on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer would be to open and listen on a specific (and uncommon) tcp server port on start-up, since only one process can hold the socket at a time a second instance could detect the socket can't be listen'd and then exit with an error. Alternatively, you could potentially create a `File` on startup (and exit if it exists).